# DBCC PAGE read page from buffer pool or directly from the file system?

Tags: sql-server, dbcc, storage-engine

We know that SQL Server always read pages from disk to memory for all its operations. So it's possible that a page in memory is different from it's counterpart in disk. I want to know the command DBCC PAGE is reading a page in memory or on disk. Thanks.

Comment: It is better to say SQL Server always uses memory for all of it's operations and retrieves data from disk only if not already in memory. Execute `CHECKPOINT; DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;` to ensure they are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We know that SQL Server always read pages from disk to memory for all its operations.

The pages are asked for from memory like most things in SQL Server. The same process applies for `DBCC PAGE` as it does for other read operations in SQL Server.